# Unable to launch an Eclipse *.product application

Tags: eclipse, plugins, equinox

I have imported an Eclipse product which consists of a set of plugins. The main plugin, say com.xxx.plugin, has a `pluginstub.product` file in it and depends on a number of other plugins.
This main plugin also contains a `Stub.java` class which implements `IApplication` and a `StubPlugin.java` which implements `AbstractUIPlugin`.

The product is configured with `com.xxx.pluginstub` as Product and `com.xxx.Stub` as Application. However, when I try to run the product, I get a ClassNotFoundException for `Stub` and `StubPlugin` classes which are in the same project as the product.

Looks like some kind of misconfiguration to me. How can I locate and fix the cause of this?

Comment: How are you running this? By building the RCP with Export Product? Or by using Run As > Eclipse Application?

Comment: @greg-449, Run As -> Eclipse Application

Answer (score 0):

Open 'Run > Run Configurations' and select the 'Eclipse Application' that you are running.

On the Main tab check the 'Program to Run' is the product.

On the Plug-ins tab check that all the required plug-ins are included.

Comment: Well, as a matter of fact, they are.